# seo - redirect to ssl vs optional

Tags: https

what would be best for SEO?

- force all website page to SSL using 301
- force just some page like login and registration page and make it optional for other pages.

Answer (score 0):

Google rewards for SSL regardless of what content is on the page. So, the answer is all... however you should note that its a minor reward and you shouldn't expect a massive shift, however it can give you the edge you need.